# Any app build with visual studio 2013/2015 hang

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, freeze

I have some strange problem with visual :-/ I can't build simple console application (with with windows problem it's the same). Console window don't apper, visual studio hang :-/ I don't have these problem last time I making console app (month ago I think). I have the same problem in vs 2015 and 2013 on windows 7. Somebody have the same problem ? Mayby it's some windows updated, or some visual update. I don't have this problem with. When I run built application manual (no from visual) application also hang :-/
Sample code I tried to run:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Hello");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

**SOLUTION:
That was my antivirus Avast, it don't ask, just block my app :-/ something change in latest update.**

Comment: You'll have to stop using the RC edition, it is expired.

Comment: @HansPassant I have the same on vs2013 community no rc :-/

Comment: This is also happening to me for some reason... I might reinstall and see what happens.