# Executables made with Visual Studio hang

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1, freeze

I use Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 to build my executables. As of today, 20th Nov, I find that when I try to run any of them in the VS Developer Command Prompt window, there is no output, execution hangs, and the process does not even respond to Ctrl-C. This happens even with executables which I built long ago and have worked successfully before. What's more, if I try to run an executable in the VS IDE in debug-mode, VS locks up.

What should I do to get these executables working again?

My PC's behaviour looks like the same as in [Any app build with visual studio 2013/2015 hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593036/any-app-build-with-visual-studio-2013-2015-hang) But I have never used any RC edition.

Just as in [Visual Studio Hangs in debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600581/visual-studio-hangs-in-debug) VS does indeed hang in debug-mode, but VS does not state that it is loading any symbols. My executables do not request any symbols from any network.

Windows 8.1 does start VS successfully.

I did an Avast scan on the directory tree containing all the executables I have built using VS, and Avast said NO THREAT FOUND.

I installed VS on 21st Aug, thus 91 days ago, so I wondered if a 90-day trial period had expired, but VS Community Edition 2015 is not time-limited, is it? [Visual Studio Community 2015 expiration date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235116/visual-studio-community-2015-expiration-date) informs me that there is no expiration date but does not help me with my problem. Besides, Help->About Microsoft VS->License terms tells me that my copy is registered to me, and says nothing about any time period expiring.

Comment: We've been having this question asked all week.  Uninstall Avast.

Comment: After @Hans-Passant mentioned Avast, I tried the following in Avast: Settings->Exclusions. I then added the directory which heads the directory tree containing all the executables I've built. That fixed the problem.

It wasn't obvious that the culprit was Avast: Avast didn't show any error messages when I tried to run an exe.